# Julia - defining a 2 dimensional array with an array as element in one dimension

Tags: julia

I am trying to define an array with:

- one dimension filled by another one dimensional array Int64
- the other dimension filled by regular numbers Int64

How can I do this? The dimensions are x and y.

Comment: Your question seems contradictory, and appears to be asking for something that is not logically possible, or that makes no sense. Are you perhaps using the word 'dimension' wrong? And what do you mean by 'array' (vector, matrix or higher-dimensional)?

Comment: for example I want to define an array that is like this: arr1[i]=arr2[l, arr3[k]]. How do I define arr2?

Comment: I think you are mixing up arrays and the _indices_ of the arrays. What you wrote now just means "element number `i` in `arr1` is set equal to element `(l, arr3[k])` of `arr2`". It doesn't explain what is actually _inside_ `arr2`, just that it is a 2-dimensional array, and that `arr1` and `arr3` are vectors.

Comment: the index of the array is another array yes

Comment: `arr3` is a vector, but we don't know what `arr3[k]` is, except that it is an element in `arr3`. I assume it is an integer number, since you are using it as an index.

Comment: yes it is an integer and it is an element in arr2.

Comment: The way you are writing it, `arr3[k]`is not an element in `arr2`, but it is a valid _index_ into `arr2`. You are mixing up the _contents_ and the _indices_ of `arr2`. Do you mean instead to say that `arr2[l, k] = arr3`?

Comment: No. arr3[k] is a valid index into arr2!

Comment: OK, but what do you want to have inside `arr2`?

Comment: The problem is how to declare it. If I declare it as arr2=Array{Float64,2}(length1, length2) it gives out an error.

Comment: OK, you want to know how to initialize a matrix? Depends on the version of Julia. But on version 1.0 you can try `arr2 = Array{Float64,2}(undef, length1, length2)`. Or use the `zeros` function.

Comment: ΟΚ Thanks. I will try and inform you.

Comment: it gives out the following error: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching Array{Float64,1}(::Int64)

Answer (score 0):

Your use of "dimension" is vague, but perhaps you want a Matrix{Number}:

```
julia> array = Matrix{Number}([1.5 2.5; 1 2])
2×2 Array{Number,2}:
 1.5  2.5
 1.0  2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear. Another possible answer is that you need a `Vector` of `Vector`s (rather than a `Matrix`)

```
julia> arr = Vector{Int64}[]
0-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}

julia> push!(arr,[1,2,3])
1-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 2, 3]

julia> push!(arr,[4,5,6])
2-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 2, 3]
 [4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need to define an array that is 2-dimensional, (x, y) as dimensions and the first dimension is filled with numbers and the second with a one dimensional array.

Comment: @Vasl What you've written here is still not precise. I suggest editing your question to include "psuedo-code" of what you are hoping your array will look like.